# Select row in paging gridview based on unique cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have a gridview with paging enabled and a textbox where the user can enter a string value used to select the row in the gridview with a column that matches the string value. The column's data is not the primary key and is not listed in the datakeynames.

I've found an example that solves the problem for a non-paging gridview. In an event handler for a button control associated with the textbox:

```
    protected void SelFrame_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string requestedFrame = tbSelFrame.Text;
        if (requestedFrame != "")
        {
            int index = (from DataControlField col in gvFrame.Columns
                            where col.HeaderText == "Name"
                            select gvFrame.Columns.IndexOf(col)).FirstOrDefault();

            var query = from GridViewRow row in gvFrame.Rows
                        where row.Cells[index].Text == requestedFrame
                        select row;
            GridViewRow result = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {
                int selectedIndex = result.DataItemIndex;
                if (selectedIndex > -1)
                    gvFrame.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

As noted, when the value being searched is on a non-visible page of the gridview, **this line returns null:**

```
 GridViewRow result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I find the matching row in a gridview with paging enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the value as a datakey instead, and then do something like this:

```
gvFrame.SelectedIndex = gvFrame.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().First(r => 
    (string)gvFrame.DataKeys[r.RowIndex]["foo"] == requestedFrame).RowIndex;
```

Comment: I've added the field for the search value to the datakeynames property of the gridview: DataKeyNames="FrameId,FrameName" and used "FrameName" in place of "foo" in your example. This works fine if the matching row is in the current page, but when it is in another page I get the run-time error: Sequence contains no matching element. I don't know exactly what the error refers to. Have I missed something in your explanation? Thank you for your time.